# erro método "login" utilizando orientação a objetos php e pdo

Tags: php, pdo, classes

boa tarde,
Estou com erro ao logar na minha pagina restrita...

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function logar() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\jauport\loginAdmin.php on line 85
Call Stack
```

Estou fazendo uma pagina de login em php utilizando orientação a objetos e fiz o método abaixo para logar no meu banco e recuperar minhas informações gravadas

```
public function logar($email, $senha)
    {

        try{
        $sel_usu = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE ema_usujauport = ? AND sen_usujauport = ? ";
        $sel_usu = $this->con->Connect()->prepare($sel_usu);
        $sel_usu->bindValue(1, $this->nome);
        $sel_usu->bindValue(2, $this->email);
        $sel_usu->execute();
        if($sel_usu->rowCount()==1):
           return  true;
        else:
           return false;
        endif;
        }
        catch(PDOException $erro_login){
        'erro'.$erro_login->getMessage();


        }

    }
```

abaixo eu estou recuperando o valor retornado pelo meu select

```
<?php



                if(isset($_POST['logar'])):
                   $login = new Usuario();

                   $email = $_POST['email'];
                   $senha = $_POST['senha'];

                   $login->setEmail($email);
                   $login->setSenha($senha);

                   $login = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
                   $login = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "senha", FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);



                   if($login->logar()):/*aqui ocorre o erro*/
                   header("location: restrito/index.php; ");

                   else:
                   echo 'Erro ao logar';
                   endif;
                endif;
                ?>
```

Comment: Nas linhas anteriores você redefine login não sei por quê.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como deve ser feito:

                `$login = new Usuario();`

```
               $email =filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
               $senha =filter_input(INPUT_POST, "senha", FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);

               $login->setEmail($email);
               $login->setSenha($senha);
           $login->logar();
```

Explicando o que você fez:
Você definiu uma varia login ( ok)
você substituiu ela por  email e depois por senha sobreposição de objetos e não colocou os objetos nos locais corretos. ( motivo do erro)